# How to set expiration date "Today" on teams with POWER AUTOMATE

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams, power-automate-desktop, microsoft-teams-js

I want to set TEAMS status message automatically.

So, I will use POWER AUTOMATE and using below method.

But I don't know how to set expiration date, "TODAY" without any number.

Please let me know how to set.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Just use the date then?  Work out how to get the end of the day in your relevant region and use that, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in Power Automate called `utcNow()` which gets the current date+time ('now') in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) format. It gets UTC as a standardized time that you can convert if needed to your own local time.

See more info on both of these points here: https://www.powertechtips.com/get-todays-date-power-automate/